# C# - XSD Validation

Tags: xml, xsd, xmlschemaset

I'm trying to build a XSD validation, I have 03 XSD

.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.esocial.gov.br/schema/evt/evtAdmissao/v02_02_00" targetNamespace="http://www.esocial.gov.br/schema/evt/evtAdmissao/v02_02_00" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
  <xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" schemaLocation="xmldsig-core-schema.xsd"/>
  <xs:element name="eSocial">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="evtAdmissao">
          <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Evento Admissão</xs:documentation>
          </xs:annotation>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element ref="ds:Signature"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.esocial.gov.br/schema/evt/evtCS/v02_02_00" targetNamespace="http://www.esocial.gov.br/schema/evt/evtCS/v02_02_00" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
  <xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" schemaLocation="xmldsig-core-schema.xsd"/>
  <xs:element name="eSocial">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="evtCS">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="infoCS">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:documentation>Informações relativas às Contribuições Sociais devidas à Previdência Social e a Outras Entidades e Fundos.</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="natInfo">
                      <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:annotation>
                          <xs:documentation>Natureza da informação</xs:documentation>
                        </xs:annotation>
                        <xs:restriction base="x:byte">
                          <xs:pattern value="\d"/>
                        </xs:restriction>
                      </xs:simpleType>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>                    
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="Id" type="xs:ID" use="required"/>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>                   
        <xs:element ref="ds:Signature"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>     
</xs:schema>
```

.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.esocial.gov.br/schema/evt/evtInsApo/v02_02_00" targetNamespace="http://www.esocial.gov.br/schema/evt/evtInsApo/v02_02_00" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
  <xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" schemaLocation="xmldsig-core-schema.xsd"/>
  <xs:element name="eSocial">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="evtInsApo">
          <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Insalubridade, periculosidade e aposentadoria especial</xs:documentation>
          </xs:annotation>
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="ideEvento" type="TIdeEveTrab">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:documentation>Informações de Identificação do Evento</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="ideEmpregador" type="TEmpregador">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:documentation>Informações de identificação do empregador</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="ideVinculo" type="TIdeVincEstagCoop">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:documentation>Informações de Identificação do Trabalhador e do Vínculo. Aplicar uma das seguintes regras, de acordo com a categoria do trabalhador.</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="insalPeric" minOccurs="0">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:documentation>Informações sobre o ambiente de trabalho insalubre/periculoso.</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="iniInsalPeric" minOccurs="0">
                      <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation>Condições do ambiente de trabalho insalubre/periculoso - Início</xs:documentation>
                      </xs:annotation>
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                          <xs:element name="dtIniCondicao">
                            <xs:simpleType>
                              <xs:annotation>
                                <xs:documentation>Data de Início da Condição</xs:documentation>
                              </xs:annotation>
                              <xs:restriction base="xs:date">
                              </xs:restriction>
                            </xs:simpleType>
                          </xs:element>
                          <xs:element name="infoAmb" type="TinfoAmb4" maxOccurs="99">
                            <xs:annotation>
                              <xs:documentation>Detalhamento dos ambientes de trabalho em que o trabalhador desempenha atividades insalubres/periculosa.</xs:documentation>
                            </xs:annotation>
                          </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="altInsalPeric" minOccurs="0">
                      <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation>Condições do ambiente de trabalho insalubre/periculoso - Alteração</xs:documentation>
                      </xs:annotation>
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                          <xs:element name="dtAltCondicao">
                            <xs:simpleType>
                              <xs:annotation>
                                <xs:documentation>Data de Alteração da Condição</xs:documentation>
                              </xs:annotation>
                              <xs:restriction base="xs:date">
                              </xs:restriction>
                            </xs:simpleType>
                          </xs:element>
                          <xs:element name="infoamb" type="TinfoAmb4" maxOccurs="99">
                            <xs:annotation>
                              <xs:documentation>Informações sobre as condições de trabalho insalubre/periculoso.</xs:documentation>
                            </xs:annotation>
                          </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="fimInsalPeric" minOccurs="0">
                      <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation>Condições do ambiente de trabalho insalubre/periculoso - Fim</xs:documentation>
                      </xs:annotation>
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                          <xs:element name="dtFimCondicao">
                            <xs:simpleType>
                              <xs:annotation>
                                <xs:documentation>Data Término da Condição Diferenciada</xs:documentation>
                              </xs:annotation>
                              <xs:restriction base="xs:date">
                              </xs:restriction>
                            </xs:simpleType>
                          </xs:element>
                          <xs:element name="infoAmb" maxOccurs="99">
                            <xs:annotation>
                              <xs:documentation>Detalha o ambiente de trabalho em que o trabalhador desempenha atividade insalubre/periculosa</xs:documentation>
                            </xs:annotation>
                            <xs:complexType>
                              <xs:sequence>
                                <xs:element name="codAmb">
                                  <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:annotation>
                                      <xs:documentation>Código do Ambiente de Trabalho</xs:documentation>
                                    </xs:annotation>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                      <xs:minLength value="1"/>
                                      <xs:maxLength value="30"/>
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                  </xs:simpleType>
                                </xs:element>
                              </xs:sequence>
                            </xs:complexType>
                          </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="aposentEsp" minOccurs="0">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:documentation>Informações sobre o trabalho exercido em condições que ensejam a aposentadoria especial.</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="iniAposentEsp" minOccurs="0">
                      <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation>Condições do ambiente de trabalho que ensejam aposentadoria especial - Início</xs:documentation>
                      </xs:annotation>
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                          <xs:element name="dtIniCondicao">
                            <xs:simpleType>
                              <xs:annotation>
                                <xs:documentation>Data de Início da Condição</xs:documentation>
                              </xs:annotation>
                              <xs:restriction base="xs:date">
                              </xs:restriction>
                            </xs:simpleType>
                          </xs:element>
                          <xs:element name="infoAmb" type="TinfoAmb4" maxOccurs="99">
                            <xs:annotation>
                              <xs:documentation>Informações relativas ao ambiente de trabalho</xs:documentation>
                            </xs:annotation>
                          </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="altAposentEsp" minOccurs="0">
                      <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation>Condições do ambiente de trabalho que ensejam aposentadoria especial - Alteração</xs:documentation>
                      </xs:annotation>
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                          <xs:element name="dtAltCondicao">
                            <xs:simpleType>
                              <xs:annotation>
                                <xs:documentation>Data de Alteração da Condição</xs:documentation>
                              </xs:annotation>
                              <xs:restriction base="xs:date">
                              </xs:restriction>
                            </xs:simpleType>
                          </xs:element>
                          <xs:element name="infoamb" type="TinfoAmb4" maxOccurs="99">
                            <xs:annotation>
                              <xs:documentation>Informações relativas ao ambiente de trabalho</xs:documentation>
                            </xs:annotation>
                          </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="fimAposentEsp" minOccurs="0">
                      <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation>Condições do ambiente de trabalho que ensejam aposentadoria especial - Término</xs:documentation>
                      </xs:annotation>
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                          <xs:element name="dtFimCondicao">
                            <xs:simpleType>
                              <xs:annotation>
                                <xs:documentation>Data Término da Condição Diferenciada</xs:documentation>
                              </xs:annotation>
                              <xs:restriction base="xs:date">
                              </xs:restriction>
                            </xs:simpleType>
                          </xs:element>
                          <xs:element name="infoAmb" maxOccurs="99">
                            <xs:annotation>
                              <xs:documentation>Informações relativas ao ambiente de trabalho</xs:documentation>
                            </xs:annotation>
                            <xs:complexType>
                              <xs:sequence>
                                <xs:element name="codAmb">
                                  <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:annotation>
                                      <xs:documentation>Código do Ambiente de Trabalho</xs:documentation>
                                    </xs:annotation>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                      <xs:minLength value="1"/>
                                      <xs:maxLength value="30"/>
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                  </xs:simpleType>
                                </xs:element>
                              </xs:sequence>
                            </xs:complexType>
                          </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="Id" type="xs:ID" use="required"/>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element ref="ds:Signature"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:complexType name="TIdeEveTrab">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>Identificação do evento</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="indRetif">
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Indicativo de Retificação</xs:documentation>
          </xs:annotation>
          <xs:restriction base="xs:byte">
            <xs:pattern value="\d"/>
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="nrRecibo" minOccurs="0">
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Recibo arquivo a ser retificado</xs:documentation>
          </xs:annotation>
          <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:minLength value="1"/>
            <xs:maxLength value="40"/>
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="tpAmb">
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Tipo de ambiente</xs:documentation>
          </xs:annotation>
          <xs:restriction base="xs:byte">
            <xs:pattern value="\d"/>
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="procEmi">
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Processo de emissão do evento</xs:documentation>
          </xs:annotation>
          <xs:restriction base="xs:byte">
            <xs:pattern value="\d"/>
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="verProc">
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Versão do processo de emissão do evento. </xs:documentation>
          </xs:annotation>
          <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:minLength value="1"/>
            <xs:maxLength value="20"/>
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="TEmpregador">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="tpInsc">
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Tipo de Inscrição, conforme tabela 5.</xs:documentation>
          </xs:annotation>
          <xs:restriction base="xs:byte">
            <xs:pattern value="\d"/>
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="nrInsc">
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Número de Inscrição</xs:documentation>
          </xs:annotation>
          <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="\d{8,15}"/>
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="TIdeVincEstagCoop">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>Informações do vínculo - empregados, estagiários e cooperados</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="cpfTrab">
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>CPF do trabalhador</xs:documentation>
          </xs:annotation>
          <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:length value="11"/>
            <xs:pattern value="\d{11}"/>
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="nisTrab" minOccurs="0">
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>NIS</xs:documentation>
          </xs:annotation>
          <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:length value="11"/>
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="matricula" minOccurs="0">
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Matricula</xs:documentation>
          </xs:annotation>
          <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:minLength value="1"/>
            <xs:maxLength value="30"/>
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="TinfoAmb" maxOccurs="99">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>Detalha o(s) Ambiente(s) de Trabalho em que o trabalhador desempenha atividades insalubres/periculosa.</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="codAmb">
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Código do Ambiente de Trabalho</xs:documentation>
          </xs:annotation>
          <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:minLength value="1"/>
            <xs:maxLength value="30"/>
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="fatRisco" maxOccurs="999">
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:documentation>Fator de risco ao qual o trabalhador está exposto na atividade exercida no ambiente</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="codFatRis">
              <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:documentation>Código do fator de risco</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                  <xs:minLength value="4"/>
                  <xs:maxLength value="10"/>
                </xs:restriction>
              </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:element>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

I've tried to load it in a XMLSchemaSet

```
    using (XmlReader rdSchema = XmlReader.Create(GetStreamResource(resource)))
    {

        schemaSet.Add(String.Format("http://www.esocial.gov.br/schema/evt/{0}/v02.02.00", evtESocial, versao), rdSchema);
    }
```

But I've got a bunch of erros  for each XML
The First one I've got

> The 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema:element' element is not
>   supported in this context.

The second I've got

> The value for the 'base' attribute is invalid - 'x:byte' is an invalid
>   value for the 'base' attribute.

In the Third I've got

> The 'maxOccurs' attribute is not supported in this context.

I've spend hours trying to solve this, I've searched in the web, but I havent found how tofix it. Can anybody help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The first XSD is fine.

For the second XSD, change

```
<xs:restriction base="x:byte">
```

to

```
<xs:restriction base="xs:byte">
```

For the third XSD, on line 42, you're missing a closing `xs:sequence` tag, and rather than close the `xs:element` for `eSocial`, you've opened a new `xs:element`.  The final issue to resolve for the third XSD is that you have made reference to `type="TinfoAmb4"` without including a definition of a `TinfoAmb4` type.  Define `TinfoAmb4` or change the type of `infoAmb` to be something that is declared.

Comment: I get just some elements in the third XSD, I edited and put the all the third XSD file , please take a look again, the second I've solved with you coment

Comment: Your new XSD has two problems: (1) Remove  `maxOccurs="99"` from the type declaration of `TinfoAmb`; it can only go on an element declaration; (2) Provide a declaration for `TinfoAmb4`.   .... At this point, I have to bow out as you're stringing this out too long.   Next time, provide a [mcve] to make best use of the limited time we have to help you.  Good luck.